# Rails Active Scaffold problem with pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, activescaffold

I start using active_scaffold plugin for data processing (CRUD) . It works fine. but when I navigate the list page with pagination, the browser address bar displays like below,

http://domain.com/admin/models#as_admin__models:2:undefined:undefined

How can I remove this kind of "undefined:undefined" parameters. Can any one help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.